Fixing a key that does not work in Linux Wayland without xmodmap
I bought a new keyboard and the right shift key doesn't work. However, I think it is a problem with firmware/software, not hardware.
If I run xev  and If I press to "A"

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
root 0x397, subw 0x0, time 1329942, (158,-25), root:(2128,94),
state 0x10, keycode 38 (keysym 0x61, a), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (61) "a"
XFilterEvent returns: False

If I run xev  and If I press to "right shift"

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
root 0x397, subw 0x0, time 1459660, (158,-25), root:(2128,94),
state 0x10, keycode 97 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
XFilterEvent returns: False

It works something like xmodmap -e "keycode 97 = Control_R" on X11.
Is it possible to fix this without using a 3rd party daemon on wayland?
I tried both gnome and kde
By the way, it doesn't work in windows either
I modified some layouts and changed keyboard layout but I couldn't solve. I expect to work properly.

What events do you get from an evemu-record for this key?

@grawity_u1686
EV_MSC / MSC_SCAN             458887
EV_KEY / KEY_RO               0
------------ SYN_REPORT (0) ---------- +65ms

Please [edit] the info you posted as comment into the question itself.
